# Community about Rocky Linux

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What is a community where I can get an answer to my question about Rocky Linux?

> Is Rocky Linux OK to use on a government project in terms of security?
>
> The reason to use Rocky Linux on the project is that they support Rocky Linux.
>
> I heard that Rocky is CentOS's successor.
>
> Does it have a critical security vulnerability?

Comment: Your quoted question is off topic here. [ask] Maybe you intended another site. Asking for an on-topic Stack Exchange site is on-topic but please research & reflect that in your post. Ask 1 question in a post. Please avoid social & meta commentary in post.

Comment: I edited your post to only ask for the site recommendation.

Comment: Having worked on government projects - it very much would depend on what the specifications given for the project was.

Answer (score 15):

While there are some [Rocky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=rocky) questions over on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I doubt any of your example questions would fly there.

From their on-topic help page:

> If your question is about:
>
> - Using or administering a *nix desktop or server
> - The Unix foundation underlying MacOS (but generally not frontend application questions)
> - The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)
> - Shell scripting
> - Applications packaged in *nix distributions (note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)
> - UNIX C API and System Interfaces ( within reason )

Your example questions ask:

> Is Rocky Linux OK to use on a government project in terms of security?

This is impossible to answer by random people on the internet. First of all we don't know which government you mean and not all governments are born equal. Secondly we can't know the conditions of the project, those differ per case. And last: Security is such a broad topic that without details no definitive answer can be formulated.

The specific question can't be asked anywhere on the SE network.

> I heard that Rocky is CentOS's successor.

This seems like an easy researchable fact that we don't need a question and answer for in the body of knowledge that SE sites try to build.

> Does it have a critical security vulnerability?

Yes. There is at least one not yet found vulnerability.